# Can Inheritance and Polymorphism make my code less redundant?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

public class Student

```
   private String name;
   private String id;
   private static double grade;
   private Midterm midtermScore;
   private FinalExam finalExamScore;

   public Student() {
      super();
   }

   public Student(String name, String id, Midterm midtermScore, FinalExam 
      finalExamScore) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
      this.midtermScore = midtermScore;
      this.finalExamScore = finalExamScore;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public double getGrade() {
      grade = midtermScore.getMidtermScore() + 
      finalExamScore.getTotalScore();
      return grade;
   }
```

public class Midterm

```
    private int numberOfQuestions;
    private int numberOfQuestionsCorrect;
    private final double WEIGHT = 0.4;
    private double midtermScore;

    public Midterm(int numberOfQuestions, int numberOfQuestionsCorrect) {
        super();
        this.numberOfQuestions = numberOfQuestions;
        this.numberOfQuestionsCorrect = numberOfQuestionsCorrect;
    }

    public int getNumberOfQuestions() {
        return numberOfQuestions;
    }
    public void setNumberOfQuestions(int numberOfQuestions) {
        this.numberOfQuestions = numberOfQuestions;
    }
    public int getNumberOfQuestionsCorrect() {
        return numberOfQuestionsCorrect;
    }
    public void setNumberOfQuestionsCorrect(int numberOfQuestionsCorrect) {
        this.numberOfQuestionsCorrect = numberOfQuestionsCorrect;
    }

    public double getMidtermScore() {
        this.midtermScore =(numberOfQuestionsCorrect*100)/numberOfQuestions;
        return midtermScore * WEIGHT;
    }
```

public class FinalExam

```
    private double grammarScore;
    private double spellingScore;
    private double lengthScore;
    private double contentScore;

    private final double GRAMMARWEIGHT = 0.3;
    private final double SPELLINGWEIGHT = 0.2;
    private final double LENGTHWEIGHT = 0.2;
    private final double CONTENTWEIGHT = 0.3;

    private final double WEIGHT = 0.6;
    private double totalScore;

    public FinalExam(double grammarScore, double spellingScore, double 
                     lengthScore, double contentScore) {
        super();
        this.grammarScore = grammarScore;
        this.spellingScore = spellingScore;
        this.lengthScore = lengthScore;
        this.contentScore = contentScore;
    }

    public FinalExam(FinalExam[] finalScores) {
        this.finalScores = finalScores;
    }
    public double getGrammarScore() {
        return grammarScore;
    }
    public void setGrammarScore(double grammarScore) {
        this.grammarScore = grammarScore;
    }
    public double getSpellingScore() {
        return spellingScore;
    }
    public void setSpellingScore(double spellingScore) {
        this.spellingScore = spellingScore;
    }
    public double getLengthScore() {
        return lengthScore;
    }
    public void setLengthScore(double lengthScore) {
        this.lengthScore = lengthScore;
    }
    public double getContentScore() {
        return contentScore;
    }
    public void setContentScore(double contentScore) {
        this.contentScore = contentScore;
    }

    public double getTotalScore() {
        this.totalScore = (grammarScore*GRAMMARWEIGHT) + 
        (spellingScore*SPELLINGWEIGHT) + (lengthScore*LENGTHWEIGHT) + 
        (contentScore*CONTENTWEIGHT);
        return totalScore*WEIGHT;
    }
```

Main Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student[] students = new Student[5];
    String[] names = new String[5];
    String[] ids = new String[5];
    String[] letterGrades = new String[5];

    Midterm m1 = new Midterm(50, 40);
    FinalExam f1 = new FinalExam(100, 90, 100, 80);
    Student s1 = new Student("Alan", "111", m1, f1);
    names[0]=s1.getName();
    ids[0]=s1.getId();

    Midterm m2 = new Midterm(40, 26);
    FinalExam f2 = new FinalExam(75, 80, 100, 60);
    Student s2 = new Student("Bill", "222", m2, f2);
    names[1]=s2.getName();
    ids[1]=s2.getId();

    Midterm m3 = new Midterm(45, 39);
    FinalExam f3 = new FinalExam(89, 94, 85, 89);
    Student s3 = new Student("Cate", "333", m3, f3);
    names[2]=s3.getName();
    ids[2]=s3.getId();

    Midterm m4 = new Midterm(35, 30);
    FinalExam f4 = new FinalExam(90, 45, 40, 68);
    Student s4 = new Student("Dave", "444", m4, f4);
    names[3]=s4.getName();
    ids[3]=s4.getId();

    Midterm m5 = new Midterm(100, 73);
    FinalExam f5 = new FinalExam(45, 56, 48, 62);
    Student s5 = new Student("Frank", "555", m5, f5);
    names[4]=s5.getName();
    ids[4]=s5.getId();

    students[0] = s1;
    students[1] = s2;
    students[2] = s3;
    students[3] = s4;
    students[4] = s5;

    String letterGrade;
    int i = 0;
    for(Student s : students) {
        if(s.getGrade() >= 90.0) {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }else if(s.getGrade() >= 80.0) {
            letterGrade = "B";
        }else if(s.getGrade() >= 70.0) {
            letterGrade = "C";
        }else if(s.getGrade() >= 60.0) {
            letterGrade = "D";
        }else
            letterGrade = "F";
        letterGrades[i] = letterGrade;
        i++;
    }

    int i = -1;
    for(++i; i<=4; i++) {
        if(i==4)
            System.out.print(String.format("%s%4s %5s%s %5s%s %11s", "|", 
                             names[i], "|", ids[i], "|", letterGrades[i], 
                             "|"));
        else
            System.out.print(String.format("%s%4s %6s%s %5s%s %11s", "|", 
                             names[i], "|", ids[i], "|", letterGrades[i], 
                             "|"));
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

First off, I apologize if my code is not formatted correctly, please feel free to edit my format and I will try to change it accordingly.

I recently started programming in Java and finished my coding assignment for this week. The problem asked to hardcode 5 students information (name, id, midterm grade, and final grade). Then the program had to output the student's name and id with a letter grade that represented their gpa.

My professor stressed the importance of using inheritance and polymorphism but I really do not see how I can utilize it. We went through composition, inheritance, and polymorphism last week but for this assignment, I did not see any way to make the code easier by applying anything other than composition without purposely making it more complex.

I think the problem comes down to practice and since my background is extremely limited, can anyone offer any suggestions on how I can improve my code? whether it is using inheritance, polymorphism, or any other method that I can practice?

With more time and practice I can get a better grasp of the language, and I figured one way to get better is by asking for feedback on my code where I am sure there is room for improvement.

Unfortunately, my professor is a busy person and not very good with e-mails and tutoring hours for this week has been cancelled, so I will appreciate any feedback even if it is not on polymorphism and inheritance.

Comment: There could be an `Exam` interface with a `getScore()` method, and `MidTermExam` and `FinalExam` implement `Exam`.  Then a `Student` takes a `List<Exam>` or `Exam exam1, Exam exam2` in it's constructor instead of having direct knowledge of `MidTermExam` and `FinalExam`.

Comment: The polymorphism would help in this way : You are creating two different classes for midterm and final exam and you have to sepcifically know which class to call when, in case you have added the classes to same class with the constructor  or the methods overloaded then you will have to just pass the right parameter at the right position and the class will itself take care of the case. 
Regarding Inheritance, you can inherit the total score method as the output is similar ( score * weight ) but only input varies.

Comment: I read through all your comments and I added a new class which was ComputeScore which actually made my code a lot smoother and cleaner. It computes the midterm and final scores and has a method of getting the total score which is a parameter of the student class.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a bit of redundant code.

I won't write the code for you but I will point out a few things I saw right away.

Both Midterm and Final Exam are a type of test, perhaps test or exam could be a good super class or interface?  I am sure you could just ask the test itself what the score is and instead of calculating the score at the end of the program, have the score calculated in each object itself.

Instead of storing just the score of the midterm and the final exam in the student.  I would recommend actually storing the midterm and final exam objects in the student.

You could then ask the student for his final grade directly.  The student would then use the midterm and final exam objects to calculate the final score.

I would recommend NOT using the `String[] names = new String[5];`, `String[] ids = new String[5];`, and `String[] letterGrades = new String[5];` arrays.  When printing out the students and their grades go directly to the student object and call `getName()`, `getId()`, etc...

Instead of an Array for students, you might consider using a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), like a [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or a [Hashset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).